# Displaying all comments for a ruby on rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm another Rails newbie and have followed the Ruby tutorial on creating a blog.

Each post has many comments and the comments belong to the posts.

I can see the comments in the individual blogs and have created a show link to show the individual comment.

What I'd really like to do is create an index page for comments which shows all of them. I created an index action in the comments controller:

```
 def index
     @title = "All comments"
     @comments = Comment.all
end
```

And an accompanying index page,

## All comments

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    Comment: <%= @comment.body %>

<% end %>

But I get an error:

undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass

My routes file:

resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction - I think my issue is that my comments are nested in the posts.

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `comment` passed into the block:

`<% @comments.each do |comment| %>  Comment: <%= comment.body %>`

You're currently calling `@comment.body`, and `@comment` is nil because it is undefined in your controller and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

So in your loop in the view file, you are iterating over the `@comments` array, creating a `comment` object for each of the comments in `@comments`. As such, try

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %> Comment: <%= comment.body %>
```

Comment: Hi again, I now have a list of comments but I can't display the related post title. I tried <%= @posts.post_id %> (for example), but I end up with an error. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What are your associations on the `comment` and `post` models? It seems (and not positive on the syntax) that posts should `have_many :comments` and a comment should `belongs_to :post`. Then, you could do `comment.post_id` (this also means you need `post_id` on the comments database). Read up on Rails Associations for more examples of this kind of behavior :)

Comment: @Bob Sumo - There are a couple of problems with what you're trying to do with `<%= @posts.post_id %>`. First, since the instance variable is plural I'm assuming you're trying to call `post_id` on a collection of posts. You need to call `post_id` on **one** post. Your second problem is that you don't want to display the post id, but rather the post content - whatever you called it (e.g. text, content, etc.). Finally, if you did want to print out the post's id for any reason, you'd simply call `.id`. If you were trying to get a Comment's "foreign key" post id, then you would call Comment.post_id